# how to run bundle install without quiet flag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

When deploying an app with capistrano to a VPS, my deployment script is running bundle install with a quiet flag. Is there a way to make it run without the quiet flag. There's nothing in the deploy.rb file (borrowed from Ryan Bates) that seems to set it to quiet.

```
command finished in 161ms
  * 2013-06-27 12:57:07 executing `bundle:install'
  * executing "cd /home/brain/apps/dogapp/releases/2013044444 && bundle install --gemfile /home/brain/apps/dogapp/releases/2013044444/Gemfile --path /home/brain/apps/dogapp/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test"
```

Deploy.rb

```
require "bundler/capistrano"

server "198.69.696969.69", :web, :app, :db, primary: true

set :application, "dogapp"
set :user, "brain"
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/apps/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false

set :scm, "git"
set :repository, "git@github.com:braindead/dogapp.git"
set :branch, "master"

default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup" # keep only the last 5 releases

namespace :deploy do
  %w[start stop restart].each do |command|
    desc "#{command} unicorn server"
    task command, roles: :app, except: {no_release: true} do
      run "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application} #{command}"
    end
  end

  task :setup_config, roles: :app do
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/#{application}"
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/unicorn_init.sh /etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application}"
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
    put File.read("config/database.example.yml"), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
    puts "Now edit the config files in #{shared_path}."
  end
  after "deploy:setup", "deploy:setup_config"

  task :symlink_config, roles: :app do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end
  after "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:symlink_config"

  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision, roles: :web do
    unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
      puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
      puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
      exit
    end
  end
  before "deploy", "deploy:check_revision"
end
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
set :bundle_flags, "--deployment"
```

Via http://henriksjokvist.net/archive/2012/2/deploying-with-rbenv-and-capistrano/

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I won't be able to test it for a couple hours but will accept later.